# Searching addresses with Google API

Tags: iphone, search, google-maps-api-3, street-address

I am writing an iphone application when you give a search text, it locate possible addresses.

I was thinking there maybe some Google API for this. I have seen several applications with this feature.

Can anyone provide some information on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've found the API you want (looks like you have), the basic idea is to use `NSURLRequest`, `NSURLConnection`, and `NSMutableData` to construct a url (ie. `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/output?parameters`) and load the resulting data into your application.

From there, I would make use of a JSON parsing lib to convert the result string into an `NSDictionary`, so that you can use it easily in your app. This one is my favorite: http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/

good luck!

Comment: is there a way to get a list of street addresses from a google api? I have seen few applications where you give few letters of the address and it gives you list of street addresses

Comment: Sorry - I haven't run into anything like that... if you find something, post a comment back here =)